# Simple program to calculate the area of triangle

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I wonder, what do is wrong with my code because when I compile it the error in the following lines:

**hello.cob: In paragraph 'DADOS':

hello.cob:25: Error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting WORD

hello.cob: In paragraph 'FIM':

hello.cob:31: Error: syntax error, unexpected '('**

Here the source of my program:

```
   IDENTIFICATION   DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID.      TRIANG.
DATA DIVISION.

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
77  BASE    PIC 9(04) VALUE ZEROS.
77  ALTURA PIC 9(04) VALUE ZEROS.
77  HAREA   PIC 9(06) VALUE ZEROS.

SCREEN SECTION.
01  TELA.
02  BLANK SCREEN.
02  LINE 04 COLUMN 21 VALUE
"CALCULO DA AREA DE UM TRIANGULO".
02  LINE 06 COLUMN 15 VALUE
"AUTOR: Alexandre".
02  LINE 10 COLUMN 21 VALUE "ENTRE COM O VALOR DA ALTURA...".
02  LINE 12 COLUMN 21 VALUE "ENTRE COM O VALOR DA BASE...".
02  LINE 14 COLUMN 21 VALUE "ENTRE COM O VALOR DA AREA...".

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
INICIO.
    DISPLAY TELA.
DADOS.
    ACCEPT(10, 51) ALTURA.
    ACCEPT(12, 51) BASE.
CALCULO.
    MULTIPLY BASE BY ALTURA GIVING HAREA.
    DIVIDE 2 INTO HAREA.
FIM.    
    DISPLAY(14, 51) HAREA.
    DISPLAY(24, 31) "FIM DE PROGRAMA".
    STOP RUN.
```

Thanks for the help.

---

I put this 2 lines in the code:

```
   IDENTIFICATION   DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID.      TRIANG.
   DATA DIVISION.

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   77  BASE    PIC 9(04) VALUE ZEROS.
   77  ALTURA  PIC 9(04) VALUE ZEROS.
   77  HAREA   PIC 9(06) VALUE ZEROS.
   77  ESPERA  PIC 9(01) VALUE ZEROS.

   SCREEN SECTION.
   01  TELA.
   02  BLANK SCREEN.
   02  LINE 04 COLUMN 21 VALUE
   "CALCULO DA AREA DE UM TRIANGULO".
   02  LINE 06 COLUMN 15 VALUE
   "AUTOR: Alexandre".
   02  LINE 10 COLUMN 21 VALUE "ENTRE COM O VALOR DA ALTURA... ".
   02  LINE 12 COLUMN 21 VALUE "ENTRE COM O VALOR DA BASE...   ".
   02  LINE 14 COLUMN 21 VALUE "ENTRE COM O VALOR DA AREA...   ".

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   INICIO.
       DISPLAY TELA.
   DADOS.
       ACCEPT ALTURA AT LINE 10 COLUMN 51.
       ACCEPT BASE AT LINE 12 COLUMN 51.
   CALCULO.
       MULTIPLY BASE BY ALTURA GIVING HAREA.
       DIVIDE 2 INTO HAREA.
   FIM.
       DISPLAY HAREA LINE 14 COLUMN 51.
       ACCEPT ESPERA AT LINE 0 COLUMN 0.
       DISPLAY "FIM DE PROGRAMA" LINE 24 COLUMN 31.
       STOP RUN.
```

Added

```
77  ESPERA  PIC 9(01) VALUE ZEROS.
```

and

```
ACCEPT ESPERA AT LINE 0 COLUMN 0.
```

but the result is `000000`

Comment: Skimming the [`ACCEPT`](http://www.scribd.com/doc/36572982/OpenCOBOL-Programmers-Guide#outer_page_87) documentation, I wonder if this would work: `ACCEPT ALTURA AT (10, 51).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the program to work. Almost. I don't know how to keep the screen up when the program terminates, so the *result* is never visible, but at least it is possible to run the program and put in the first two numbers:

```cobol
       IDENTIFICATION   DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID.      TRIANG.
       DATA DIVISION.

       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       77  BASE    PIC 9(04) VALUE ZEROS.
       77  ALTURA PIC 9(04) VALUE ZEROS.
       77  HAREA   PIC 9(06) VALUE ZEROS.
       77  DUMMY  PIC 9(01) VALUE ZEROS.

       SCREEN SECTION.
       01  TELA.
       02  BLANK SCREEN.
       02  LINE 04 COLUMN 21 VALUE
       "CALCULO DA AREA DE UM TRIANGULO".
       02  LINE 06 COLUMN 15 VALUE
       "AUTOR: Alexandre".
       02  LINE 10 COLUMN 21 VALUE "ENTRE COM O VALOR DA ALTURA...".
       02  LINE 12 COLUMN 21 VALUE "ENTRE COM O VALOR DA BASE...".
       02  LINE 14 COLUMN 21 VALUE "ENTRE COM O VALOR DA AREA...".

       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       INICIO.
           DISPLAY TELA.
       DADOS.
           ACCEPT ALTURA AT LINE 10 COLUMN 51.
           ACCEPT BASE AT LINE 12 COLUMN 51.
       CALCULO.
           MULTIPLY BASE BY ALTURA GIVING HAREA.
           DIVIDE 2 INTO HAREA.
       FIM.
           DISPLAY HAREA LINE 14 COLUMN 51.
           DISPLAY "FIM DE PROGRAMA" LINE 24 COLUMN 31.
           ACCEPT DUMMY AT LINE 1 COLUMN 1.
           STOP RUN.
```

A much cleaner better version:

```
       IDENTIFICATION   DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID.      TRIANG.
   DATA DIVISION.

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   77  BASE    PIC 9(04) VALUE ZEROS.
   77  ALTURA PIC 9(04) VALUE ZEROS.
   77  HAREA   PIC 9(07) VALUE ZEROS.
   77  AGAIN   PIC X VALUE 'N'.

   SCREEN SECTION.
   01  TELA.
   02  BLANK SCREEN.
   02  LINE 04 COLUMN 21 VALUE
   "CALCULO DA AREA DE UM TRIANGULO".
   02  LINE 06 COLUMN 15 VALUE
   "AUTOR: Alexandre".
   02  LINE 10 COLUMN 21 VALUE "ENTRE COM O VALOR DA ALTURA [____]".
   02  LINE 10 COLUMN 50 PIC ZZZ9 Using ALTURA.
   02  LINE 12 COLUMN 21 VALUE "ENTRE COM O VALOR DA BASE...[____]".
   02  LINE 12 COLUMN 50 PIC ZZZ9 Using BASE.
   02  LINE 14 COLUMN 21 VALUE "            VALOR DA AREA..".
   02  LINE 14 COLUMN 48 PIC ZZZZZZ9 From HAREA.
   02  LINE 16 COLUMN 21 VALUE "                    FINIS...[N]".
   02  LINE 16 COLUMN 50 PIC X Using AGAIN.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   INICIO.
       DISPLAY TELA.
       PERFORM SCREENS UNTIL AGAIN  = 'Y'
       STOP RUN.
   SCREENS.
       ACCEPT TELA.
       MULTIPLY BASE BY ALTURA GIVING HAREA.
       DIVIDE 2 INTO HAREA.
       DISPLAY TELA.
```

Comment: If you, like me, don't know COBOL but want to play around: save this into a file, complete with the silly spacing before every line. Run `cobc -x triang.cob` to compile the `triang.cob` file into an executable `triang`. If you leave off the `-x`, OpenCOBOL will generate a `triang.so` that you run with `cobcrun triang`.

Comment: @sarnold Those silly spaces are reserved for line numbers. Line numbers are a must for reordering your program when you hold a big batch of [**punched cards**](http://www.google.com/search?q=punched+cards&hl=en&prmd=ivns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=aPsLToieOILw0gGx54iQDg&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CDAQ_AUoAQ&biw=1440&bih=740) inside your pretty cardboard box and you happen to fall flat on your face.

Comment: @Bo -- Just "ACCEPT" a dummy value from the screen before the "STOP RUN" and it will keep the display up until you press the "any" key.

Comment: @Belisarius, a professor loved to tell the story of a student programming in [SNOBOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNOBOL) who would make a great show of "accidentally" dropping all his cards all over the floor, pick them up in any old random order, and drop them in the card reader. SNOBOL made it easy to place a `GOTO` on every line, and the machine would figure it out. Everyone else looked horrified, as they knew the effort to re-sort their FORTRAN or COBOL program cards. Those days must have been fun, in their own way...

Comment: @sarnold *I* punched my own programs. Those complaining about re-sorting troubles did not follow _best practices_. Double smile :):)

Answer (score 2):

The reason your result is "00000" is because you are not validating the input.

As your program stands the user MUST enter four digits for each value, if only three digits are entered the calculation fails.